# I want to show a view right next to another view(which holds the button) on a Button click. Is it possible in SwiftUI for macOS?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, appkit

I want to show a view right next to another view(which holds the button) on a Button click. Is it possible in SwiftUI for macOS ?
**This is the view I want to show**

```
struct TestView1: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in

        List {
            Text("Hello TestView1")
            Text("Hello TestView1")
            Text("Hello TestView1")
            Text("Hello TestView1")
            Text("Hello TestView1")
            Text("Hello TestView1")
        }
        }.frame(minWidth: 600, idealWidth: 600, maxWidth: 800, minHeight: 400, idealHeight: 400, maxHeight: 600, alignment: .top)
        .position(x: 500, y: 420)
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
}
```

**From this Button click**

```
        Button(action: {
            self.showingDetail.toggle()
        }) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Threat Response")
                        .fontWeight(Font.Weight.bold)
                        .accentColor(Color.black)
                        .padding(.leading)
                    Spacer(minLength: 5)
                    Text("9:11 AM")

                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Suspicious activity on your trusted device")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .accentColor(Color.black)
                        .padding(.leading)
                    Spacer(minLength: 5)
                    Image(systemName: "link")
                }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.trailing)

                Text("There was some kind of suspicious activity on one of your accounts. As a precaution, Information Security")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .accentColor(Color.black)
                    .padding(.leading)

            }
            
        }
```

The view with Threat Response in the List is where my button is. And I want to show TestView1() right next to it, same as Email app.[image]